# How grep through your staged files prior to committing?

Tags: git, grep, commit, git-commit

So prior to running `git commit` I often will run the following:

```
git grep --cached -l -I "debugger"
```

I thought it was similar to:

```
git diff --cached
```

(which will show you all the changes you are about to commit, ie. will show you the diff in your staged files).

Unfortunately, I just found that the `--cached` option for `git grep` simply tells git to "only" look at everything in its index.

So how can I run `git grep` and have it only grep through my staged files?

(Yes, I know I could simply do `git diff --cached` and search in that, but I would rather have the programmatic ability to grep through my staged files.)

Comment: So, did you manage to solve this issue? I'd be interested in the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a Unix-like shell available, the answer is pretty simple:

```
git grep --cached "debugger" $(git diff --cached --name-only)
```

This will run `git grep` on the list of staged files.

Comment: This answer is good, except that `git grep` needs the `--cached` option as well.  Otherwise, the grep will be performed on the disk version of the file, not the staged version of the file.

Comment: @tanager True, thanks for the correction. I never noticed the difference as my staged files are usually identical to the files in the working tree.

Comment: This will also try to diff deleted files. Using `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=d` will filter those out. Additionally, in recent versions of git, `--staged` can be used instead of `--cached`.

Answer (score 14):

A lot of pre-commit hooks use `git diff-index --cached -S<pat> REV` to find changes which add or remove a particular pattern.  So in your case, `git diff-index --cached -Sdebugger HEAD`.  You may want to add `-u` to get a diff as well, otherwise it just identifies the offending file.

Comment: The `-S` option takes a fixed string, not a regex. (I'm not sure which you meant by "pat".) However, git diffcore recently gained the `-G<regex>` option, which ought to let you do anything you were trying to do with `git grep`. It's not in a released version yet, but is on the `git.git` master branch.

Comment: OK this gets me close to what I need, but not 100% there. This will give you a positive match for your -S<string> if it was added or deleted.  I only want a match returned if it was *added*.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get a list of files from the index (excluding deleted files).
This can be done with the following:

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD
```

Second you need to use the : prefix to access the contents of a file in the
current index (staged but not yet committed) see [gitrevisions
manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emltngtltpathgtemegem0READMEememREADMEem)
for more information.

```
git show :<file>
```

Finally here's an example of putting it all together to grep this list of files

```
# Get a list of files in the index excluding deleted files
file_list=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD)

# for each file we found grep it's contents for 'some pattern'
for file in ${file_list}; do
    git show :"${file}" | grep 'some pattern'
done
```

Also [here's an example](https://github.com/arecarn/dotfiles/blob/c249378ec8957b14c5ed653fb809abc595d1c9b4/git/bin/pre_commit_copyright_check.sh) of a git pre-commit hook that uses this method to check that the copyright years are up to date in files to be committed.