# Have git issue warnings

Tags: php, git

I'm using git (and I develop in PHP) and I have a tendency to commit debug code like `print_r`, `var_dump`, and `die` - I was wondering if I could somehow have git warn me that those functions are being called (so I don't end up pushing them to master).

Comment: search and replace is your friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, stop using those functions! You should really be using [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) which lets you step through your code, stop it at any point and see all of the variables that are available, etc.

However, even if you do continue to use them (I use them still, even though I use XDebug for a lot of debugging) you should look into [git hooks](https://book.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Answer (score 3):

You could add an commit-hook which checks these types of things, and even go as far as reject your commit. simple [google Search](http://www.google.nl/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=git%20commit%20hook#sclient=psy-ab&hl=nl&source=hp&q=git%20add%20commit%20hook&pbx=1&oq=git%20add%20commit%20hook&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=68988l69367l0l69427l4l3l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=9439d4a6d5623de7&biw=1920&bih=1115) might prove helpful on a how-to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do some research regarding [Git Hooks](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html).

These discussions may give you some clues:

- [How grep through your staged files prior to committing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102151/how-grep-through-your-staged-files-prior-to-committing)
- [How does this pre-commit hook fix trailing whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677425/how-does-this-pre-commit-hook-fix-trailing-whitespace)
- [Minify CSS files via git hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334671/minify-css-files-via-git-hook)
- [Is there a better way of writing a git pre-commit hook to check any php file in a commit for parse errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374/is-there-a-better-way-of-writing-a-git-pre-commit-hook-to-check-any-php-file-in)